# Breaking/Managing a huge regression suite

Tags: junit

Could anyone please provide some idea on breaking up (/managing/parallelizing) a huge regression suite. We have over 25000 regression tests that run each day - so its taking a huge time to run them. We are using JUnit. And the tests are testing several web services.

Appreciate your help with this.

Thanks 
Yana

Answer (score 0):

How about using Jenkins to do that? It allows for parallel running and also slave/master execution and heterogeneous testing environments

http://jenkins-ci.org/

Its also free

Comment: Thanks. But as of now we use something similar to Jenkins which cannot be replaced soon. I am looking for general best practices/strategies to deal with a huge regression suite?